# Custom activity types do not appear in report filter

Tags: civireport, civicase

When creating a report from a template (specifically the Activity Report) custom case types are not available in the filter list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, we were creating custom Activity Types and selecting used for "Cases Only."

If we change this to "Contacts and Cases," they appear in the filter list.